# Mysql intersection of two sets having comma separated value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

It will be very great-full if anyone will provide me a small help in mysql.

I have a table having 1 billion records in which one column having comma separated value.

I have a comma separated values to search.

I want to select those rows which having anyone value in that comma separated column from that string value.

e.g,
Table is A having column comma_separated like this:-

[image]

and i have a string having comma separated values "79, 62, 70, 107".

**Result will be row number 1,2,3,5,7,8,9,10 (In mention Image.)**

*I did it with regex but it is taking too much time, so i want to avoid this for optimization purpose.*

Comment: Please show us your attempts.

Comment: It is very bad database design!

Comment: Another solution i am thinking so do it with stored function(which will use loop with find_in_set function) which will provide boolean for to set and use that in query. But dont know how to do that.

Comment: _regex = r"(^|(\d*,)+)(%s)((,\d*)+|$)" %('|'.join(_comma_seprated_values))

Comment: why `row 5` and `row 7` not selected?  `79` and `62` are there in these `row`s respectively.

Comment: It is bad design but for the sake maybe user interface as a developer you face such kind of problem where the only best way to store data is using a bad design.

Answer (score 5):

You can't really optimize what you are doing.  Basically, you can run a query like this:

```
where find_in_set(79, comma_separated) > 0 or
      find_in_set(62, comma_separated) > 0 or
      find_in_set(70, comma_separated) > 0 or
      find_in_set(107, comma_separated) > 0
```

This requires a full-table scan.  And, although the performance might be slightly better than a regular expression, it still will not be efficient.

The proper way to store this data is as a junction table.  This multiplies the number of rows, so the first row in your data becomes three rows in the junction table (one for each value).

There are numerous reasons why you do not want to store lists of things as a comma-separated list.  Your values look like ids in another table, making things even worse:

- Values should be stored in their native format.  So, storing integers as strings is a bad idea.
- The native structure for lists in SQL is a table, not a list.
- Functions on tables are more powerful and string functions.
- SQL cannot use indexes (with the exception of full text indexes) for string operations.
- When you have an id referring to another table, you should have a foreign key constraint.  You cannot do that with lists stored in a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned with performance, you should consider modifying the structure of your DB. Numbers do not index well (if at all) in text-based column types.

It looks like you have constant number of integers in your "comma_separated" column.

Consider creating a separate INT type column for each of the three, i.e.:

```
num1 | num2 | num3
79   | 62   | 101
101  | 5    | 70
```

Then you could do proper selection like:

```
WHERE 
  num1 IN (79, 62, 70, 107)
  OR num2 IN (79, 62, 70, 107)
  OR num3 IN (79, 62, 70, 107)
```