# MySQL remove values from CSV value, defined by other CSV

Tags: mysql, csv

There is a very specific practical situation that got me into a very specific MySQL query problem. I wonder if it can be done in MySQL.

If I have two columns with CSV values in the MySQL database. They represent sets of numbers. I wonder if I can "subtract" one set from the other within a query.

For instance if `A="100, 234, 567, 890"` and `B="100, 123, 567"`, I want to remove all values in B from A; yielding `"234, 890"`. So I want to remove only those values from A that exist in both A and B. The values are numeric but the csv's obviously strings. Both csv values can have the values in ascending order if necessary.

(The actual csv's are separated with comma's but without spaces, I only added spaces here for readability.)

I know csv values are in general not the way to go, but in this specific situation it can't be helped.

Is there a simple and elegant solution?

EDIT: I could only get it to work, neither simple nor elegantly, if the number of values in A is capped (in this case max 6):

```
SET @A='1,2,3,4,5';
SET @B='1,3,5,6,8';
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',',
IF( LENGTH(@A)-LENGTH(REPLACE(@A,',','')) + 1 >= 1 AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( @A, ',',1 ), ',', -1 ),@B),SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( @A, ',',1 ),',',-1),NULL),
IF( LENGTH(@A)-LENGTH(REPLACE(@A,',','')) + 1 >= 2 AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( @A, ',',2 ), ',', -1 ),@B),SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( @A, ',',2 ),',',-1),NULL),
IF( LENGTH(@A)-LENGTH(REPLACE(@A,',','')) + 1 >= 3 AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( @A, ',',3 ), ',', -1 ),@B),SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( @A, ',',3 ),',',-1),NULL),
IF( LENGTH(@A)-LENGTH(REPLACE(@A,',','')) + 1 >= 4 AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( @A, ',',4 ), ',', -1 ),@B),SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( @A, ',',4 ),',',-1),NULL),
IF( LENGTH(@A)-LENGTH(REPLACE(@A,',','')) + 1 >= 5 AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( @A, ',',5 ), ',', -1 ),@B),SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( @A, ',',5 ),',',-1),NULL),
IF( LENGTH(@A)-LENGTH(REPLACE(@A,',','')) + 1 >= 6 AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( @A, ',',6 ), ',', -1 ),@B),SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( @A, ',',6 ),',',-1),NULL))
```

Result:

```
2,4
```

Probably by defining a function (and dropping them afterwards) this could get a bit more readable.

Any better solutions?

Comment: I doubt it, or if you can it wouldn't really be the way to go about it. Do this processing in a scripting language like PHP or Python, and then either write out a CSV file that can be imported, or use a database driver to insert the data to the database directly.

Comment: Not exactly efficient to do with MySQL, but here's a shot at it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31560720/mysql-intersection-of-two-sets-having-comma-separated-value

Comment: There are very specific reasons not to do it in the "normal"/"proper" way, and - that I did not say - also not to do it in PHP either, but in MySQL. B is actually in a MySQL variable, not a field, but that does not make a big difference. The link you provided only gives a solution for fixed values, not for unspecified values.